# How to retrieve a string from an object located in an array

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarray

just a quick question

I have an array with only one object in it which is a string.

How can I retrieve it into a string ?

when I do this :

```
NSLog(@"%@",[myUserInfo objectAtIndex:0]);
```

It prints the result right, but what I want to achieve is this :

```
 localNotif.alertBody = the string in the array.
```

I'm sure it is an easy thing to do but I can't figure it out.

Could you help me please ?

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: I have just modified the question. Would you mind having a look at it again please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a trick question. Have you tried:

```
localNotif.alertBody = [myUserInfo objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Thanks Eimantas. Actually this is what I was doing but still, same Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”. So I suspected it was something else which had to do with memory management. So I have removed all the releases and it works so I guess I have to find out which release is the cause of the bad Access. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Sorry about that, it was just my finger that slipped. ;-)